# Comparing Enum - Angular

Tags: angular, enums

I have a `enum` value that I get from a REST-Service, and I am trying to print in in a table

```
<td *ngIf="door.doors==Pass">No error</td>
```

In this case, `doors` is the `enum`.

I have tried to make the condition in different ways:

**1 - ==**

```
<td *ngIf="door.doors==Pass">No error</td>
```

**2- ===**

```
<td *ngIf="door.doors===Pass">No error</td>
```

**3 - =**

```
<td *ngIf="door.doors=Pass">No error</td>
```

But any of them are working (nevers appear the td). I guess that the problem is that I am comparing a `String` (Pass) with a `enum`. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `==` and `''` with the `Pass`. `==` will force the `doors` to be cast into string and check their values based on string.

```
<td *ngIf="door.doors == 'Pass'">No error</td>
```

Comment: I love when the solutions are that easy to change. This perfectly works! I ll set it as "Correct answer" in 11 minutes

Comment: Thanks. Glad to help you.